# Select the cell in a column that is not a text

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column with 20 rows. The header of the column is "MONTH." In the first 10 rows, the cells contain the text "Jan." In the next 10 rows, the cells contain the date, "18-12-2019". I want to write a macro that will loop through the column, starting from A2 and will stop at the cell that contains a date.

I have written the following code. But it is not working. Excel is saying, "The function is not defined." Pls. help me write the right code for this.

```
Sub Find_Date()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim Rng As Range

    Set Rng = Range(("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown))

    For Each cell In Rng
        If IsText(cell) = True Then: cell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: WorksheetFunction.IsText(cell) instead of IsText(cell)

Answer (score 0):

To your descripted situation:

> In the first 10 rows, the cells contain the text "Jan." In the next 10 rows, the cells contain the date

the following code would be a resolution:

```
Sub Find_Date()

    Dim row As Integer

    For row = 2 To 10
        'Do whatever you want with activesheet.cells(row,1)
    Next

End Sub
```

what excactly do you want to do with those cells?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that is more dynamic and fluid...

However, with this method you can not skip a cell row.

```
Sub Find_Date()
Dim row As Integer

For row = 2 To ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1).End(xlDown).Row
    'Use ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 1) to control the current cell (1 = First Column)
    If IsDate(ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 1).Value) = TrueThen
        ' Add Code Here to be executed if there is Date 
    Else
        ' Add Code Here to be executed if there is TEXT
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Again, the above code will not actually do anything until modify the above.

Below is a batch of code that will simply SELECT all of the cells in column 'A' that are dates.

```
Sub Find_Date()
Dim row As Integer
Dim y() As Variant
Dim z As Integer
z = 1

For row = 2 To ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).row
    If IsDate(ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 1).Value) = True Then
        ReDim Preserve y(1 To z) As Variant
        y(z) = ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 1).Address
        z = z + 1
    End If
Next
For Each x In y
    ranges = ranges + x + ", "
Next x

Range(Left(ranges, Len(ranges) - 2)).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Within the For...Next loop I want to write the code that will go through each cell of the selected range (which is a column in this case). If the data type of the cell is Text, then move to the next cell; If the data type of the cell is "Date", then just select that cell. How would I write that in code?

Comment: Please see my above edit, I have added a single line of code that would get what you are looking for. If this answers your question, then please be sure to mark this as the Answer.

Comment: I executed the following code. But nothing happened at all. Sub Find_Date()
Dim row As Integer

For row = 2 To ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).row
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsText(ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 1).Value) = False Then Cells(row, 1).Activate
Next
End Sub

Comment: Okay, i have modified my above to code to add more insight. Right now, this code pretty much does nothing. It simply loops through the first column.

Comment: Okay, i got bored at work and made a few modifications. I have made two sets of code above. Take your pick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test_only()         'Only for test
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim dateCell As Range

    Set Rng = Range(("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown))    'Set range as desired
    Set dateCell = Find_Date(Rng)
    Debug.Print dateCell.Address                'dateCell now holds the first non-text cell (range)
End Sub

Function Find_Date(Rng As Range) As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Set Find_Date = Nothing
    For Each cell In Rng
        If WorksheetFunction.IsText(cell) = False Then
            Set Find_Date = cell
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: I executed the first Macro, but it's not working. It says: Compile Error. Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"